# What is a useful starting idea to think about this simple graph problem?

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, alternative-proof

I would like to prove the statement that there are $2^{\binom{n-1}{2}}$ simple graphs are there with vertex set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ such that every vertex has even degree.

The thing that confuses me is the $\binom{n-1}{2}$: this is the place that I use to start attacking the problem, I guess the $n-1$ means the vertex other than itself, so from a vertex we can have $n-1$ edge joining the vertex to the remaining vertex and the two means choosing two vertices to create an edge.

But somehow if I use this line of reasoning, it seems that we can only have a maximum degree for each vertex is 2.

Can anybody please give me some helpful hints so that I can start thinking in the correct direction?

Many thanks!

Comment: Hint: How many (labeled) graphs are there on $n-1$ vertices if you ignore the "even-degree" condition? How can you relate this number to the number of $n$-vertex graphs that satisfy the degree condition?

Comment: @GregoryJ.Puleo Is it correct to say there are $(n-1)!$ labelled graph on $n-1$ vertices?

Comment: No, that is not correct. Alex G's answer goes along similar lines to my hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints: The $\binom{n-1}{2}$ refers to the number of unordered pairs of vertices selected from the first $n-1$ vertices. We have $2$ raised to this power because for each such pair of vertices, we can either choose for them to be connected by an edge or not. The $n^{\text{th}}$ vertex is used to make sure that every vertex has even degree.

Can you use this information to account for every such graph?

Comment: Show that every simple graph on $n-1$ vertices uniquely determines a simple graph on $n$ vertices with all even degrees and vice versa. Thus the two sets of graphs are in bijection.